# How to change the extension in view using codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, codeigniter-3, smarty3

Here's my problem I setup Codeigniter 3 in my local and use an thirdparty (MX thing) now that I have adjusted the file path, I wanted to change the file extension that is being fetch the controller.

```
$this->load->view('welcome_message');
```

---

I change the file in views from:

```
welcome_message.php
```

to this

```
welcome_message.html
```

---

Now I get this error

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: welcome_message.php
```

---

but I wanted to use the .html extension becuase the folder path that I will be using will only contain html/js/css (template folder) files only (i will separate the php files to template folder). How can this possibly happen?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks guys!

Comment: Change $this->load->view('welcome_message'); To include("application/views/welcome_message.html");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change extension to html, you can use html in a php file, just don't open php tag.

EDIT :

If you really have to change the ext, just do :

```
$this->load->view('welcome_message.html');
```

Comment: Your request didn't pass through the CI index, what's your URL and you .htaccess ?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to change it using route configuration in `application/config/routes.php`

Then, you can use:

```
$route['[your controller]/welcome_message'] = '[your controller]/welcome_message.html';
```

For for information about routes, you can check official documentarion here:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Or you can use Static pages:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Regards.