# Why are view files in CodeIgniter saved with .php extension?

Tags: codeigniter

From the CodeIgniter docs, I noticed that the view files are saved with `.php` extension, even if they only contain `html`. Is there a logical reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not compulsory to save view files with the only .php extension we can also save them as HTML files, But to load the HTML views we also need to specify the filename with an extension like `$this->load->view('my_view.html')`.

Also, you can check this link for the same discussion [view extension in CodeIgniter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205056/how-to-change-the-extension-in-view-using-codeigniter-3)

**Q:** When we load any class in CodeIgniter like we load the models, libraries in our controllers without specifying its extensions so how CodeIgniter loads the exact file with that name.

**A:** For this, There are the system functions defined in the CodeIgniter which concat the .php extension with the class name we pass e.g `$this->load->library('form_validation')`

***For Example:*** How CodeIgniter 3 actually loads **liberaries** If you can check the system file in  `system/core/Common.php` line no ~141 function 
 `load_class` for liberaries

So it will load `system/libraries/Form_validation.php` file

I hope this will make you clear that why view files in CodeIgniter saved with .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is a PhP framework, so it assumes the user is (eventually) going to use PhP.

Also, it isn't necessarily bad practice to always use .php instead of .html since .php handles html just fine. Could be viewed as potential future proofing your code.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of using the .php extension is that a server can be configured to not display the contents of the file. In other words, the lines of text (php code) that are eventually output to the browser (as html) cannot be seen directly. This provides a layer of security by hiding implementation details from the website user.

Answer (score 0):

Because Codeigniter is a PHP MVC (Model-View-Controller) Framework. The *view* files are .php because they use PHP scripts. That's the idea, but it's not mandatory. You can include pure HTML. The *view* files are called by "name-of-the-view-without-the-extension".